# SqlCeException Not enough storage

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, system.data.datatable

I have scanner application on Windows Mobile 6.5 device.

The application keeps crashing after I scan 100 items or so (where I open SqlCe Connection and execute SQL query to populate temporary DataTable with query result).

Here how my C# code looks like:

```
// Search with SQL
modFunctions.tempItemTable = new AppScanDataSet.itemDataTable();
string connectionString = @"Data Source='" + modFunctions.AppPath() + "AppScan.sdf'; Max Database Size = 512; Max Buffer Size = 4096;";
string strSql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE Barcode = '" + modFunctions.strBarcode +  "'";

using (SqlCeConnection mConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();

    //SqlCeConnection mConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCeCommand mCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strSql, mConnection);

    // Read all rows from the table into a dataset (note, the adapter automatically opens connection)
    SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(mCommand);
    adapter.Fill(modFunctions.tempItemTable);

    mConnection.Close();
    mConnection.Dispose();
}
```

Error on crash is:

```
AppScan.exe
SqlCeException
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation
```

What can be the problem? I am clearing out tempItemTable (with `Dispose()` and `Clear()`). I also added `mConnection.Close()` and `mConnection.Dispose()`... but it didn't help.

Also, when I go to Settings > System > Memory.. when application crashed, it seems like I have enough memory available (30MB out of 100MB).

Do I need to dispose `adapter`? or `mCommand`?

Comment: Try to get a little more info from the Exception (which line, stack trace, InnerException). Also, are the Barcodes unique? Are ther big Blob columns in the table?

Comment: What is the size of your AppScan.sdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running out of memory. Using DataSet with Windows Mobile is not recommnded, use array or list instead.